# Simple (Very Easy to Make) RPG Game Simulation in Python and Turtle

Tags: python, object-oriented, game, role-playing-game, turtle-graphics

The code creates a very simple/easy RPG game, with 2 classes `Jedi` and `Orc`. The data is visualized using `turtle`. Each class has a method of `attack` (`lightsaber_attack` for `Jedi`), which has an argument that must be either a `Jedi` or `Orc` instance. The `.health` attribute of the attacked one will be reduced by `.power` of the attacker. If `.health` is not positive, then the image of the character will disappear. By design, each character can attack itself.

### Simulation

```
luke.lightsaber_attack( orc_1 )
luke.lightsaber_attack( orc_2 )
orc_1.attack( luke )
orc_2.attack( orc_2 )
```

### Questions

- How can I make the code to be easily understood by teenagers? (in a tutorial)
- How can I make it more compact?
- Are there any missing important features of Python's OOP that are important to be explained to students? (other than `super` and inheritance)

### Image Links

- [jedi.gif](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwit1aug3sLfAhVLqI8KHXkhDVQQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphotobucket.com%2Fgifs%2Fluke%2520skywalker%2520gif&psig=AOvVaw0FAdw5ahuUpluC-GQ9eF2D&ust=1546093763401668)
- [orc.gif](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/DependableIllArmyworm-max-1mb.gif)
- [darkorc.gif](https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/attack_3.gif)
- [damaged.gif](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjD8IOF4MLfAhVINo8KHbO7DaUQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgifer.com%2Fen%2F3IsK&psig=AOvVaw1Jlevg6MxHqG_Xv4XBkeTg&ust=1546094231810744)

### Full code

```
import turtle
import time

jedi_gif = "/home/asus/Arief_tempo/images/random/jedi.gif"
orc_gif = "orc.gif"
darkorc_gif = "darkorc.gif"
damaged_gif = "damaged.gif" 

turtle.register_shape( jedi_gif )
turtle.register_shape( orc_gif )
turtle.register_shape( darkorc_gif )
turtle.register_shape( damaged_gif )

class JediLuke:
    def __init__(self):
        self.power = 300
        self.health = 300

        self.img = turtle.Turtle( shape = jedi_gif )
        self.damaged_img = turtle.Turtle( shape = damaged_gif, visible = False )

        self.img.penup()
        self.damaged_img.penup()

    def lightsaber_attack(self, enemy):
        self.img.setpos(enemy.img.pos()[0], enemy.img.pos()[1])
        enemy.damaged_img.showturtle()
        enemy.health += - self.power
        time.sleep(1)

        enemy.damaged_img.hideturtle()
        if enemy.health < 0:
            enemy.img.hideturtle()

        self.img.setpos(200, 0)

    def change_pos(self, pos):
        self.img.setpos(pos[0], pos[1])
        self.damaged_img.setpos(pos[0], pos[1] + 150)


class Orc:
    def __init__(self, health, gif_image):
        self.power = 100
        self.health = health

        self.img = turtle.Turtle( shape = gif_image )
        self.damaged_img = turtle.Turtle( shape = damaged_gif, visible = False )

        self.img.penup()
        self.damaged_img.penup()

    def attack(self, enemy):
        current_pos = self.img.pos()
        self.img.setpos(enemy.img.pos()[0], enemy.img.pos()[1])
        enemy.damaged_img.showturtle()
        enemy.health += - self.power

        time.sleep(1)

        enemy.damaged_img.hideturtle()
        if enemy.health < 0:
            enemy.img.hideturtle()

        self.img.setpos(current_pos[0], current_pos[1])

    def change_pos(self, pos):
        self.img.setpos(pos[0], pos[1])
        self.damaged_img.setpos(pos[0], pos[1] + 150)


luke = JediLuke()
luke.change_pos( [200, 0] )

orc_1 = Orc( health = 400 , gif_image = orc_gif)
orc_1.change_pos( [-200, 100] )

orc_2 = Orc( health = 200, gif_image = darkorc_gif )
orc_2.change_pos( [-200, -100] )
```

Comment: As an aside: Luke Skywalker attacking orcs is a jarring mix-up of universes.

Comment: I upvoted @Reinderien 's comment, but I also +1 this question because Luke Skywalker. Fighting Orcs.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast noted....

Comment: why name the attacks differently?

Answer (score 10):

```
jedi_gif = "/home/asus/Arief_tempo/images/random/jedi.gif"
```

It's unclear why this image has an absolute path but no others do. They should probably all be relative, as the other three are.

Especially if this is for a tutorial, you need to add docstrings to all of your functions.

This:

```
self.img.setpos(enemy.img.pos()[0], enemy.img.pos()[1])
```

can use argument expansion, i.e.:

```
self.img.setpos(*enemy.img.pos())
```

That pattern can be used elsewhere you're indexing into the position.

This:

```
enemy.health += - self.power
```

should be

```
enemy.health -= self.power
```

Comment: Thanks. Why need docstrings? the functions will be explained in class. If I use `f(*pos)` then I need to explain further about function to the kids (which makes the subject a bit more tedious to them), but using `f(pos[0], pos[1])` would be more obvious.

Comment: "Explaining it [presumably verbally] in class" is not good enough. The code should document itself. You should be able to hand a copy to a programmer who has not attended your class and have some reasonable expectation that they'll understand what's going on.

Answer (score 6):

Just a note of something that was particularly jarring when viewing your code; for stylistic reasons, you shouldn't have spaces on either side of the arguments:

```
turtle.register_shape( jedi_gif )
```

Instead you want:

```
turtle.register_shape(jedi_gif)
```

This is covered in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) in the section [Whitespace in Expressions and Statements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements). It's good to follow PEP 8 because it makes it easier for others (and in the long run, yourself) to read your code:

Answer (score 2):

One guiding principle in programming is to write DRY code, [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Your `JediLuke` class and your `Orc` class are almost the same. Since you are already teaching about classes, you should also teach about inheritance (maybe later, but eventually).

```
import turtle
import time

class Entity:
    def __init__(self, power, health, img, damaged_img, *position):
        self.power = power
        self.health = health
        self.img = turtle.Turtle(shape=img)
        self.damaged_img = turtle.Turtle(shape=damaged_img, visible=False)

        self.img.penup()
        self.damaged_img.penup()
        self.set_position(*position)

    def attack(self, enemy):
        """Attack an enemy"""
        current_pos = self.img.pos()
        self.img.setpos(*enemy.img.pos())
        enemy.damaged(self.power)
        self.img.setpos(*current_pos)

    def damaged(self, power):
        """Take damage from `power`"""
        self.damaged_img.showturtle()
        self.health -= power
        time.sleep(1)
        self.damaged_img.hideturtle()
        if self.health <= 0:
            self.img.hideturtle()

    def set_position(self, pos):
        self.img.setpos(*pos)
        self.damaged_img.setpos(pos[0], pos[1] + 150)


class Jedi(Entity):
    def lightsaber_attack(self, enemy):
        super().attack(enemy)

    attack = None  # to ensure it cannot be called...


class Orc(Entity):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    jedi_gif = "jedi.gif"
    orc_gif = "orc.gif"
    darkorc_gif = "darkorc.gif"
    damaged_gif = "damaged.gif" 

    turtle.register_shape(jedi_gif)
    turtle.register_shape(orc_gif)
    turtle.register_shape(darkorc_gif)
    turtle.register_shape(damaged_gif)

    luke = Jedi(200, 0)
    orc_1 = Orc(400, orc_gif, -200, 100)       
    orc_2 = Orc(200, darkorc_gif, -200, -100)
```

This also has the calling code under an [`if __name__ == "__main__"` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script and the whitespace fixed according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add use os path for cross compatibility with other os's.  Since mac uses a "/", and windows "\"

otherwise if you copy your code to windows and run the script you will get an error saying it's not a valid directory

use

```
from os import path

path.join("Directory1", "Directory2", "filename.gif") 
# Equal to "Directory1/Directory2/filename.gif
# or "Directory1\Directory2\filename.gif
```